# Liferay Hook - Redirection not working

Tags: java, liferay

I have a problem with redirection , the hook is not directing back on adding message. The code I have written thus far is:

```
public class EditMessageCustomAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction  {     

    private static final String BB_CODE_EDITOR_WYSIWYG_IMPL_KEY = "editor.wysiwyg.portal-web.docroot.html.portlet.message_boards." +
            "edit_message.bb_code.jsp";

    public static final String[] BOOLEANS = {"true", "t", "y", "on", "1"};

    @Override
    public void processAction(
             StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
                PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
                ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws Exception {
        _log.info("Hook processAction >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");


        System.out.println("Hook processAction >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"); 
        String cmd = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, Constants.CMD);

        MBMessage message = null;

        try {
            UploadException uploadException =
                (UploadException)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                    WebKeys.UPLOAD_EXCEPTION);

            if (uploadException != null) {
                if (uploadException.isExceededLiferayFileItemSizeLimit()) {
                    throw new LiferayFileItemException();
                }
                else if (uploadException.isExceededSizeLimit()) {
                    throw new FileSizeException(uploadException.getCause());
                }

                throw new PortalException(uploadException.getCause());
            }
            else if (cmd.equals(Constants.ADD) ||
                     cmd.equals(Constants.UPDATE)) {

                message = updateMessage(actionRequest, actionResponse);
            }
            else if (cmd.equals(Constants.DELETE)) {
                deleteMessage(actionRequest);
            }
            else if (cmd.equals(Constants.LOCK)) {
                lockThreads(actionRequest);
            }
            else if (cmd.equals(Constants.SUBSCRIBE)) {
                subscribeMessage(actionRequest);
            }
            else if (cmd.equals(Constants.UNLOCK)) {
                unlockThreads(actionRequest);
            }
            else if (cmd.equals(Constants.UNSUBSCRIBE)) {
                unsubscribeMessage(actionRequest);
            }

            System.out.println("Message Posted + cmd " + cmd);
            if (Validator.isNotNull(cmd)) {
                String redirect = getRedirect(
                    actionRequest, actionResponse, message);
                //originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
                System.out.println("Before Send redi" + redirect);
                sendRedirect( portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse,redirect,null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (e instanceof NoSuchMessageException ||
                e instanceof PrincipalException ||
                e instanceof RequiredMessageException) {

                SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass());

                setForward(actionRequest, "portlet.message_boards.error");
            }
            else if (e instanceof CaptchaMaxChallengesException ||
                     e instanceof CaptchaTextException ||
                     e instanceof DuplicateFileException ||
                     e instanceof FileExtensionException ||
                     e instanceof FileNameException ||
                     e instanceof FileSizeException ||
                     e instanceof LiferayFileItemException ||
                     e instanceof LockedThreadException ||
                     e instanceof MessageBodyException ||
                     e instanceof MessageSubjectException ||
                     e instanceof SanitizerException) {

                UploadException uploadException =
                    (UploadException)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                        WebKeys.UPLOAD_EXCEPTION);

                if (uploadException != null) {
                    String uploadExceptionRedirect = ParamUtil.getString(
                        actionRequest, "uploadExceptionRedirect");

                    actionResponse.sendRedirect(uploadExceptionRedirect);
                }

                SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass());
            }
            else if (e instanceof AssetCategoryException ||
                     e instanceof AssetTagException) {

                SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass(), e);
            }
            else {
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();

                if (cause instanceof SanitizerException) {
                    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, SanitizerException.class);
                }
                else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

    }






        protected boolean isDisplaySuccessMessage(PortletRequest portletRequest)
                throws SystemException {

                if (!SessionErrors.isEmpty(portletRequest)) {
                    return false;
                }

                ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)portletRequest.getAttribute(
                    WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

                Layout layout = themeDisplay.getLayout();

                if (layout.isTypeControlPanel()) {
                    return true;
                }

                String portletId = (String)portletRequest.getAttribute(
                    WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);

                try {
                    LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet =
                        themeDisplay.getLayoutTypePortlet();

                    if (layoutTypePortlet.hasPortletId(portletId)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (PortalException pe) {
                    if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        _log.debug(pe, pe);
                    }
                }

                Portlet portlet = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById(
                    themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), portletId);

                if (portlet.isAddDefaultResource()) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }


        protected void addSuccessMessage(
                ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {

                PortletConfig portletConfig = (PortletConfig)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                    JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_CONFIG);

                boolean addProcessActionSuccessMessage = GetterUtil.getBoolean(
                    portletConfig.getInitParameter("add-process-action-success-action"),
                    true);

                if (!addProcessActionSuccessMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                String successMessage = ParamUtil.getString(
                    actionRequest, "successMessage");

                SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "requestProcessed", successMessage);
            }

        protected void sendRedirect(
                PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
                ActionResponse actionResponse, String redirect,
                String closeRedirect)
            throws IOException, SystemException {

            System.out.println("sendRedirect >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"); 

            if (isDisplaySuccessMessage(actionRequest)) {
                addSuccessMessage(actionRequest, actionResponse);
            }

            if (Validator.isNull(redirect)) {
                System.out.println("sendRedirect 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"); 
                redirect = (String)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.REDIRECT);
                System.out.println("sendRedirect 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + redirect); 
            }

            if (Validator.isNull(redirect)) {
                System.out.println("sendRedirect 2 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"); 
                redirect = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirect");
                System.out.println("sendRedirect 2 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + redirect); 
            }

            if ((portletConfig != null) && Validator.isNotNull(redirect) &&
                Validator.isNotNull(closeRedirect)) {
                System.out.println("sendRedirect 3 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"); 
                redirect = HttpUtil.setParameter(
                    redirect, "closeRedirect", closeRedirect);
                System.out.println("sendRedirect 4 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + redirect); 

                SessionMessages.add(
                    actionRequest,
                    PortalUtil.getPortletId(actionRequest) +
                        SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_CLOSE_REDIRECT,
                    closeRedirect);

                System.out.println("sendRedirect 5 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + PortalUtil.getPortletId(actionRequest) +
                        SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_CLOSE_REDIRECT); 
            }

            if (Validator.isNull(redirect)) {
                System.out.println("sendRedirect final >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"); 
                return;
            }

            // LPS-1928

            HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(
                actionRequest);

            if (BrowserSnifferUtil.isIe(request) &&
                (BrowserSnifferUtil.getMajorVersion(request) == 6.0) &&
                redirect.contains(StringPool.POUND)) {

                String redirectToken = "&#";

                if (!redirect.contains(StringPool.QUESTION)) {
                    redirectToken = StringPool.QUESTION + redirectToken;
                }

                redirect = StringUtil.replace(
                    redirect, StringPool.POUND, redirectToken);
            }

            redirect = PortalUtil.escapeRedirect(redirect);

            if (Validator.isNotNull(redirect)) {
                actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirect);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
                PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
                RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
            return originalStrutsPortletAction.render(portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
        }

        protected String getForward(PortletRequest portletRequest) {
            return getForward(portletRequest, null);
        }

        protected String getForward(
            PortletRequest portletRequest, String defaultValue) {

            String forward = (String)portletRequest.getAttribute(
                getForwardKey(portletRequest));

            if (forward == null) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            else {
                return forward;
            }
        }


        public static String getForwardKey(PortletRequest portletRequest) {
            String portletId = (String)portletRequest.getAttribute(
                WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);

            String portletNamespace = PortalUtil.getPortletNamespace(portletId);

            return portletNamespace.concat(WebKeys.PORTLET_STRUTS_FORWARD);
        }


        protected void setForward(PortletRequest portletRequest, String forward) {
            portletRequest.setAttribute(getForwardKey(portletRequest), forward);
        }


        /*@Override
        public void processAction(
                ActionMapping actionMapping, ActionForm actionForm,
                PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
                ActionResponse actionResponse)
            throws Exception {

            String cmd = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, Constants.CMD);

            MBMessage message = null;

            System.out.println("processAction ***********************************************************");

            try {
                UploadException uploadException =
                    (UploadException)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                        WebKeys.UPLOAD_EXCEPTION);

                if (uploadException != null) {
                    if (uploadException.isExceededLiferayFileItemSizeLimit()) {
                        throw new LiferayFileItemException();
                    }
                    else if (uploadException.isExceededSizeLimit()) {
                        throw new FileSizeException(uploadException.getCause());
                    }

                    throw new PortalException(uploadException.getCause());
                }
                else if (cmd.equals(Constants.ADD) ||
                         cmd.equals(Constants.UPDATE)) {

                    message = updateMessage(actionRequest, actionResponse);
                }
                else if (cmd.equals(Constants.DELETE)) {
                    deleteMessage(actionRequest);
                }
                else if (cmd.equals(Constants.LOCK)) {
                    lockThreads(actionRequest);
                }
                else if (cmd.equals(Constants.SUBSCRIBE)) {
                    subscribeMessage(actionRequest);
                }
                else if (cmd.equals(Constants.UNLOCK)) {
                    unlockThreads(actionRequest);
                }
                else if (cmd.equals(Constants.UNSUBSCRIBE)) {
                    unsubscribeMessage(actionRequest);
                }

                if (Validator.isNotNull(cmd)) {
                    String redirect = getRedirect(
                        actionRequest, actionResponse, message);

                    sendRedirect(actionRequest, actionResponse, redirect);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof NoSuchMessageException ||
                    e instanceof PrincipalException ||
                    e instanceof RequiredMessageException) {

                    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass());

                    setForward(actionRequest, "portlet.message_boards.error");
                }
                else if (e instanceof CaptchaMaxChallengesException ||
                         e instanceof CaptchaTextException ||
                         e instanceof DuplicateFileException ||
                         e instanceof FileExtensionException ||
                         e instanceof FileNameException ||
                         e instanceof FileSizeException ||
                         e instanceof LiferayFileItemException ||
                         e instanceof LockedThreadException ||
                         e instanceof MessageBodyException ||
                         e instanceof MessageSubjectException ||
                         e instanceof SanitizerException) {

                    UploadException uploadException =
                        (UploadException)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                            WebKeys.UPLOAD_EXCEPTION);

                    if (uploadException != null) {
                        String uploadExceptionRedirect = ParamUtil.getString(
                            actionRequest, "uploadExceptionRedirect");

                        actionResponse.sendRedirect(uploadExceptionRedirect);
                    }

                    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass());
                }
                else if (e instanceof AssetCategoryException ||
                         e instanceof AssetTagException) {

                    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass(), e);
                }
                else {
                    Throwable cause = e.getCause();

                    if (cause instanceof SanitizerException) {
                        SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, SanitizerException.class);
                    }
                    else {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ActionForward render(
                ActionMapping actionMapping, ActionForm actionForm,
                PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
                RenderResponse renderResponse)
            throws Exception {

            System.out.println("Render *****************************************");
            try {
                ActionUtil.getMessage(renderRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof NoSuchMessageException ||
                    e instanceof PrincipalException) {

                    SessionErrors.add(renderRequest, e.getClass());

                    return actionMapping.findForward(
                        "portlet.message_boards.error");
                }
                else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }

            return actionMapping.findForward(
                getForward(renderRequest, "portlet.message_boards.edit_message"));
        }
    */
        protected void deleteMessage(ActionRequest actionRequest) throws Exception {
            long messageId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "messageId");

            MBMessageServiceUtil.deleteMessage(messageId);
        }

        protected String getRedirect(
            ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse,
            MBMessage message) {

            if (message == null) {
                String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirect");

                return redirect;
            }

            int workflowAction = ParamUtil.getInteger(
                actionRequest, "workflowAction", WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH);

            if (workflowAction == WorkflowConstants.ACTION_SAVE_DRAFT) {
                return getSaveAndContinueRedirect(
                    actionRequest, actionResponse, message);
            }
            else if (message == null) {
                return ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirect");
            }

            ActionResponseImpl actionResponseImpl =
                (ActionResponseImpl)actionResponse;

            PortletURL portletURL = actionResponseImpl.createRenderURL();

            portletURL.setParameter(
                "struts_action", "/message_boards/view_message");
            portletURL.setParameter(
                "messageId", String.valueOf(message.getMessageId()));

            return portletURL.toString();
        }

        protected String getSaveAndContinueRedirect(
            ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse,
            MBMessage message) {

            String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "redirect");

            boolean preview = ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "preview");

            PortletURL portletURL =
                ((ActionResponseImpl)actionResponse).createRenderURL();

            portletURL.setParameter(
                "struts_action", "/message_boards/edit_message");
            portletURL.setParameter("redirect", redirect);
            portletURL.setParameter(
                "messageId", String.valueOf(message.getMessageId()));
            portletURL.setParameter("preview", String.valueOf(preview));

            return portletURL.toString();
        }

        protected void lockThreads(ActionRequest actionRequest) throws Exception {
            long threadId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "threadId");

            if (threadId > 0) {
                MBThreadServiceUtil.lockThread(threadId);
            }
            else {
                long[] threadIds = StringUtil.split(
                    ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "threadIds"), 0L);

                for (int i = 0; i < threadIds.length; i++) {
                    MBThreadServiceUtil.lockThread(threadIds[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void subscribeMessage(ActionRequest actionRequest)
            throws Exception {

            long messageId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "messageId");

            MBMessageServiceUtil.subscribeMessage(messageId);
        }

        protected void unlockThreads(ActionRequest actionRequest) throws Exception {
            long threadId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "threadId");

            if (threadId > 0) {
                MBThreadServiceUtil.unlockThread(threadId);
            }
            else {
                long[] threadIds = StringUtil.split(
                    ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "threadIds"), 0L);

                for (int i = 0; i < threadIds.length; i++) {
                    MBThreadServiceUtil.unlockThread(threadIds[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void unsubscribeMessage(ActionRequest actionRequest)
            throws Exception {

            long messageId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "messageId");

            MBMessageServiceUtil.unsubscribeMessage(messageId);
        }

        protected MBMessage updateMessage(
                ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
            throws Exception {

            System.out.println("updateMessage *****************************************");

            PortletPreferences portletPreferences = actionRequest.getPreferences();

            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(
                WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

            long messageId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "messageId");

            long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
            long categoryId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "mbCategoryId");
            long threadId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "threadId");
            long parentMessageId = ParamUtil.getLong(
                actionRequest, "parentMessageId");
            String subject = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "subject") + "<<<Indu>>>" ;
            String body = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "body");

            String format = GetterUtil.getString(
                portletPreferences.getValue("messageFormat", null),
                MBMessageConstants.DEFAULT_FORMAT);

            //if (!isValidMessageFormat(format)) {
                format = "html";
            //}

            List<ObjectValuePair<String, InputStream>> inputStreamOVPs =
                new ArrayList<ObjectValuePair<String, InputStream>>(5);

            try {
                UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest =
                    PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);

                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    String fileName = uploadPortletRequest.getFileName(
                        "msgFile" + i);
                    InputStream inputStream = uploadPortletRequest.getFileAsStream(
                        "msgFile" + i);

                    if ((inputStream == null) || Validator.isNull(fileName)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    ObjectValuePair<String, InputStream> inputStreamOVP =
                        new ObjectValuePair<String, InputStream>(
                            fileName, inputStream);

                    inputStreamOVPs.add(inputStreamOVP);
                }

                boolean question = ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "question");
                boolean anonymous = ParamUtil.getBoolean(
                    actionRequest, "anonymous");
                double priority = ParamUtil.getDouble(actionRequest, "priority");
                boolean allowPingbacks = ParamUtil.getBoolean(
                    actionRequest, "allowPingbacks");

                ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(
                    MBMessage.class.getName(), actionRequest);

                boolean preview = ParamUtil.getBoolean(actionRequest, "preview");

                serviceContext.setAttribute("preview", preview);

                MBMessage message = null;

                if (messageId <= 0) {
                    if (getBoolean(
                            PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.CAPTCHA_CHECK_PORTLET_MESSAGE_BOARDS_EDIT_MESSAGE),false) ) {


                        CaptchaUtil.check(actionRequest);
                    }

                    if (threadId <= 0) {

                        // Post new thread

                        message = MBMessageServiceUtil.addMessage(
                            groupId, categoryId, subject, body, format,
                            inputStreamOVPs, anonymous, priority, allowPingbacks,
                            serviceContext);

                        if (question) {
                            MBThreadLocalServiceUtil.updateQuestion(
                                message.getThreadId(), true);
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        // Post reply

                        message = MBMessageServiceUtil.addMessage(
                            parentMessageId, subject, body, format, inputStreamOVPs,
                            anonymous, priority, allowPingbacks, serviceContext);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    List<String> existingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                        String path = ParamUtil.getString(
                            actionRequest, "existingPath" + i);

                        if (Validator.isNotNull(path)) {
                            existingFiles.add(path);
                        }
                    }

                    // Update message

                    message = MBMessageServiceUtil.updateMessage(
                        messageId, subject, body, inputStreamOVPs, existingFiles,
                        priority, allowPingbacks, serviceContext);

                    if (message.isRoot()) {
                        MBThreadLocalServiceUtil.updateQuestion(
                            message.getThreadId(), question);
                    }
                }

                PermissionChecker permissionChecker =
                    themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker();

                boolean subscribe = ParamUtil.getBoolean(
                    actionRequest, "subscribe");

                /*if (!preview && subscribe &&
                    MBMessagePermission.contains(
                        permissionChecker, message, ActionKeys.SUBSCRIBE)) {*/

                    MBMessageServiceUtil.subscribeMessage(message.getMessageId());
                /*}*/

                return message;
            }
            finally {
                for (ObjectValuePair<String, InputStream> inputStreamOVP :
                        inputStreamOVPs) {

                    InputStream inputStream = inputStreamOVP.getValue();

                    StreamUtil.cleanUp(inputStream);
                }
            }
        }


        private boolean getBoolean(String value, boolean defaultValue) {
                if (value == null) {
                    return defaultValue;
                }

                value = value.trim();

                value = StringUtil.toLowerCase(value);

                if (value.equals(BOOLEANS[0]) || value.equals(BOOLEANS[1]) ||
                    value.equals(BOOLEANS[2]) || value.equals(BOOLEANS[3]) ||
                    value.equals(BOOLEANS[4])) {

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }


        public static boolean isValidMessageFormat(String messageFormat) {
            String editorImpl = PropsUtil.get(BB_CODE_EDITOR_WYSIWYG_IMPL_KEY);

            if (messageFormat.equals("bbcode") &&
                !(editorImpl.equals("bbcode") ||
                  editorImpl.equals("ckeditor_bbcode"))) {

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(EditMessageCustomAction.class);

    }
```

Requires some of the core objects of portal server, which is packaged in `portal-impl`, that cannot be added as dependency in the hook lib. Please suggest a good practise .

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you've copied an awful lot of Liferay's code into your hook. As you ask for best practice: This is not it. You seem to create a Struts Action Hook, and that typically only needs one method, in which you do whatever you want before or after the delegation to the originalStrutsAction.

If you copy Liferay's implementation, it naturally might refer to classes that are not part of the API - you'll need to implement that functionality yourself. However, a Struts Action typically is used to add some additional functionality to what already happens. You're not stating what you actually want to achieve (other than writing a hook) and I'm not going to decipher the amount of code that you post - let alone try it out to figure out what you want to do.

Best Practice: Implement your additions, then delegate to originalStrutsAction. Or the other way around. Don't copy Liferay's implementation. And, by all means: *Whatever happens, do not add portal-impl.jar to the dependencies of your plugin*